# How can share an object between an ASP.Net page and other projects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object (ClientConfiguration) that I use on almost every page on my site, as well as in many methods that exist in related projects that get compiled into the website.

What I am doing now is creating and populating the object on each page load, and storing it in the HttpContext. This works great for anything in the UI project; and for anything in the dll projects, I pass the ClientConfiguration to any methods that may need to use it.

What I would rather do is have a "global" property that is shared among all of the related projects so I don't have to pass it around.

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps an easier approach is to store the contents of this object in the database? You can also wrap up the access in an object

Comment: Depending on how large your application is, it might be better to treat your configuration as a dependency and use dependency injection to tell your classes about configuration options instead of having a static way of getting this information.  If you're going to do unit-testing, this will help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

After you add System.Web.dll as reference in your other library projects, you can access the object in HttpContext directly, no need to pass as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on where initial configuration is being stored (xml file, database or something else) but you’ll see the point.

If these are global configuration settings that are same for all application users you can create a class like this

```
public class Config
{
    public static ClientConfiguration Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Application["clientconfig"] == null)
            { 
                //Fill object from database
            }

            return HttpContext.Current.Application["clientconfig"] as ClientConfiguration;
        }

        set
        { 
            //store object in database 

            //invalidate what is stored in application object 
            //so that it will be refreshed next time it's used
            HttpContext.Current.Application["clientconfig"] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This will store the `ClientConfiguration` in global Application object and make it available in all pages so you don’t have to create it in page load.

You can just use it like this

```
private void Foo()
{
    ClientConfiguration config = Config.Current;
}
```

If you have multiple projects that need to share same data then it’s best to store the object in database or in shared XML file and create new class library project so that you can just include reference to the Config class.